# "Null" HTML DOM Element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm writing a framework which uses javascript/html as the client and it-doesn't-matter as the back end.

From time to time I have a need to store data in the HTML DOM.  Ideally I'd like to store the data against a DOM element, but I want this element to have no UI impact.

At the moment I'm thinking I'll use a <span> with no text content and decorate it with attribution so that my framework can pick up that it is a data container and behave appropriately.

Is there a better choice?  (For the avoidance of doubt, I know there are other ways I could do things - I'm not interested in these, purely in what the best HTML element to use to contain data without having a UI impact).

Edit (explanation of architecture):
I've created a server-side technology which is based on top of a generic reporting engine I've previously created.  This server-side thing essentially works as a web-server - this might seem like an unusual choice to make but, given organisational constraints, it's the best choice - for the sake of argument, assume this is true.  One of the things I need this system to do is to generate dynamic forms to capture data which is in a tree-like form.  This has been fine and has worked well - my question is because when a sub-form is hidden (for example, the user has made all required decisions in a given sub-section of the data), I destroy the data capture elements - if the form is embedded within a parent form which needs access to the data captured in a destroyed sub-form, I need a way of embedding the data into the DOM so it can be collected to be passed back to the server.  The requirements are a lot more complicated that this, but it'll take far too long to detail them all.

Comment: Why do you need to store data in the HTML DOM? Please provide enough information to prove that this is not an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well (and for the avoidance of doubt), the HTML elements are not supposed to store data. If you really want to, use the `<input type="hidden">` element.

For your purpose, I recommend (in that order) using localstorage or cookie or web database.

here are some resources :

- localstorage : http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html
- cookie : http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/setcookie/
- web database : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm

As JLRishe pointed out, if you need, for whatever reason, a text node storage, then span is a good choice as div is (and as lot of elements are as long as you `display: none` them).

Comment: OP has not made it clear why they want to store data in their DOM. If they need to store it as a text node for whatever reason, then `<input type="hidden">` would not be suitable.

Comment: that's true, I've edited my answer to highlight that.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create javascript objects...

```
var myData ={
    property1:"aaaaa",
    property2:500,
    property3:{morestuff1:"AAA", ... },
    property3:["list1", "list2", ... ],
   ....
}
```

Easy to access and easy to manipulte within the DOM if you need.
No UI impact.... (no render)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious choice here is to use HTML data attribute. If you have a table and want to store info about the table that is not shown to the user - you could just:

```
<table id="mytable" data-id="2000" data-rows="20" data-whatever="whatever">
```

You could then get it with jQuery easely with:

```
$("#mytable").data('rows');
```

Which would give you 20.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to store data in the DOM, if you're not actually using it for the purpose of layout. Yikes!

To better suit your needs, HTML5 provides a JavaScript API for handling client side storage. Depending on your circumstances, you have 2 options to choose from. The APIs are exactly the same, the only difference is the lifetime of the storage.

They are:

- localStorage: Local storage is persistent; data stored in local storage is even available to the webpage after the user closes the browser completely and reopens it.
- sessionStorage: As the name says, this data is only available for the current session.

Here's a link that will help you better understand these APIs so you can solve your particular problem: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp